# create a column with multiple if conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 columns: balls, black, white. balls is all entries in the df. black is boolean (1 for black and 0 for not), and white is also boolean (1 and 0).
I would like to create a column using:

- if Black then B
- if white then W
- else B

Comment: Columns of what (by df you mean dataframe, I guess)? Please post your attempt at solving this issue, the result, and how is it different than what you expected.

Comment: I assumed this was `pandas` given the term `df`. If that is incorrect please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68991303/edit) your question to tag the appropriate data library if that was incorrect.

Comment: Regardless of data processing library or structure please include a _small_ subset of your data as a __copyable__ piece of code that can be used for testing as well as your expected output for the __provided__ data. See  [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you all the for feedback! I apologies for not being clear with my question.  I am new to this platform and it seems that I am not aware of the basic rules. I will do my diligence to to streamline collaboration and feedbacks. My attempts involved several ways including and and or, and where but failed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might answer your question:

```py
import random

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create balls
balls = []
N = 100 # user to edit

for i in range(N):
    colour = ''
    if np.random.random() > 0.5:
        colour = 'B'
    else:
        colour = 'W'
    balls.append(colour)

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'balls': balls})

# add black column
df['black'] = df['balls'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 'B' else 0)

# add white column
df['white'] = df['balls'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 'W' else 0)
```

This results in a dataframe with 3 columns - `'balls'` containing the colour, `'black'` containing `1` if the ball is black otherwise `0`, and `'white'` which is `1` if the ball is white otherwise `0`